# Linq query error - Unable to cast object of type 'V1.Controllers.Loan' to type 'System.IConvertible

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

In my first query (`stringQuery`) I am trying to pass a string date.

**Linq Query 1:**

```
 var stringQuery = (from p in db.Database_CRE_Events
                    select new Loan()
                    {
                        cDate = p.LastUpdated

                    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Then I  convert the string date from the first query into `datetime` field `dtt`. This is because, in my second query (`dateQuery`) I need to use to this date parameter (as datetime), in my where clause which only accepts datetime type field.

```
 if (stringdQuery != null && stringdQuery.cDate.HasValue)
       {
           dtt = Convert.ToDateTime(stringdQuery); 

       }
```

**Linq Query 2:**

```
   var dateQuery = (from p in db.Database_CRE_Events.Where(c => c.LastUpdated == dtt)
                    select new Loan()
                    {
                        latest = p.Date

                    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

However, when I execute this function - on the client-side, I get thrown error – *Unable to cast object of type 'STW_V1.Controllers.Loan' to type 'System.IConvertible*

*Error on the following line:*

`dtt = Convert.ToDateTime(stringQuery);`

Am I missing something in the code?

Apology in advance, if the above explanation is not clear but please feel free to ask any further questions.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Because `stringQuery` returns a single `Loan` object which does not implement `IConvertible`  I suspect you meant to get the `cDate` property form the object instead:

```
if (stringdQuery != null && stringdQuery.cDate.HasValue)
{
    dtt = Convert.ToDateTime(stringdQuery.cDate); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That helped a lot.  I would like to ask, if you know what  `IConvertible` means?  Thank for your feedback

Comment: @user3070072 Read [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx).  It's an interface that defines methods to convert to various built-in types.  [`Convert.ToDateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky38w316.aspx) tries to use that interface to convert the value to a `DateTime`.  If the input is not convertible to `DateTime` then an `InvalidCastException` is thrown.